# How to add n-th child class using *ngFor with ionic2,angular2

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using ionic2. I have an array for `product`. I am displaying product with grid view.

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let i of rows" #myElem>
        <ion-col class="productlist" col-6 *ngFor="let p of product | slice:(i*2):(i+1)*2" (click)="nav(p.details.id)" > 
            <div class="product-image">
                <img src="{{p.details.P_IMAGES[0].URL}}" alt="Product 1">
            </div>

            <div class="product-blk">   
                <div class="product-title">{{p.details.P_TITLE}}</div>
                <div class="product-price">
                    <img src="./assets/images/rupee-yellow.svg" alt="Rupee">{{p.details.PRICE_SALE}}
                    <span>{{p.details.PRICE_REGULAR}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="product-desc">
                    {{p.Desc}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.productlist {
      animation: FadeIn 1s linear;
      animation-fill-mode: both;
      animation-delay: .5s
  }

@keyframes FadeIn { 
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(.1);
  }

  85% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

It works perfectly, but I need to set animation delay on each grid; I need a custom CSS class like this:

```
.productlist:nth-child(1),.productlist:nth-child(2),..
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the CSS you will need:

```
.productlist:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.productlist:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.productlist:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.productlist:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
```

You can write a for loop in a CSS preprocessor like Sass, for brevity:

```
@for $i from 1 through 4 {
    .productlist:nth-child(#{$i}){
      animation-delay: $i + s;
    }
}
```

Comment: No.I didn' t got err msg But no changes.I Just add 
down vote
accept
You need an for loop in scss:

@for $i from 1 through 4 {
    .productlist:nth-child(#{$i}){
      animation-delay: $i * 1000;
    }
}.

Comment: Can u say pls how to find slution